# Change yearRange for Datepicker - jQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a button with an event for datepicker, but the code is done in core, so I don't want to change anything from there. I created an event for changing the yearRange.

The problem is that when I first click on that button the calendar popup is displayed and hidden, an on a second click it opens with correct yearRange, also my default value is reseted with today date.

```
(function($){
     $(".wcfm_datepicker").one('click', function(){
         $(".wcfm_datepicker").datepicker( "option", "yearRange", "1920:2010" );
     });
})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE  -- now it works, but I get an error when I hover every day from calendar**

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <script>
    (function($){
      $('.wcfm_datepicker').each(function() {
          $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1920:2010"
          });
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined

Comment: Are you initiating the datepicker before (e.g. `$(".wcfm_datepicker").datepicker()`) Or this code is the first time?

Comment: Is already initialized from core code of the package.

Comment: So probably when you click on it for the first time it's not only set the range but also show it, like it suppose to do. Just for test, put a button somewhere and on replace `$(".wcfm_datepicker").one` with the button. If I'm right, it should solve the problem..

Comment: If I undestand correctly, I create a new button and add a new ID and add it to my code for test. But the calendar is not showing up. If I do basic $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); works, but now with the range that I want it.

Comment: I meant something like this: https://jsbin.com/xujuhog/edit?html,js,output.

Comment: Ok, but in this example the range is still not set.

Comment: I think it does. After you click on the button the year navigation (the arrow buttons around the year) are disabled.